# ASP.NET Core Web Application Template for VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-core

I know that for some reason VB.NET was not supported in the first release of Core, but this is meant to be fixed in 2.0...

Can someone tell me where they hide the ASP.NET Core Web Application template? It's there for C# but is missing for VB.NET

VS version 15.3.4

.NET Core 2.0 SDK has been installed

[image: C#]

[image: VB]

Thank you

Comment: did you try selecting .NET core under VB ?

Comment: Shyju - that just contains Console App | Class Library | Unit Test Project | xUnit Test Project

Comment: you want to create web apps using vb.net with .net core 2.0

Comment: yes. it is not an available asp.net core web apps on vb.net templates in .net core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Asp.Net Core doesn't support VB.Net in .Net Core. you can see detailed information from the following a link https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/587

Comment: That was version 1.0 - version 2.0 rectified that, according to MS, and now there is a .NET Core subset, but the web application template is missing